# дочерний элемент при клике меняет стили второго родительского блока

Tags: css, style

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на дочерний элемент одного родительского блока , менялись стили другого родительского блока, только с помощью css.
Например: 
    `<div class="one">
     <button>Кнопка</button>
</div>
<div class="two"></div>`
 Чтобы при нажатии на button  менялись стили .two

Comment: Теоретически, что-то такое  можно было бы реализовать при помощи псевдокласса `:has` https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#has-pseudo стилем вроде этого `.one:has(> button:active) + .two {...}` но на практике это пока не поддерживается https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has

Answer (score 1):

```css
    div.one:active + div.two{
      color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div class='one'>
  <button>Change</button>
</div>

<div class='two'>Test</div>
```

Comment: Клик срабатывает не только при клике на кнопку, но и на весь div `.one`.